# Creating an application with multiple targets in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, targets

Is there any way to create a project/application which will have multiple targets.
Its same as how we create multiple targets for an iPhone application in XCode.
Basically I have an app which has to be made for different targets, with almost all the similar functionalities but with little change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Configuration Manager to add additional configurations to the list of Debug and Release. Then for each configuration go to Project/Properties/Build/Conditional compilation symbols and add a symbol used with your configuration or target, eg. make it SILVERLIGHT;WINDOWS_PHONE;CUSTOMVERSION1

Then in your code you can say

```
#if CUSTOMVERSION1
    Debug.WriteLine("This is a CUSTOMVERSION1");
#else
    Debug.WriteLine("This is not CUSTOMVERSION1");
#endif
```

Otherwise - if you want to make bigger changes - you would create another project and link files from one project to another project - project/Add/Existing Item//Add As Link(an option in the "Add" button menu). You can then add more files or add different versions of these files as needed. You could use [Project Linker](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5e730577-d11c-4f2e-8e2b-cbb87f76c044) to do it faster.

Comment: The first option is enough for me, but how do i specify different Icons and SplashScreens for different targets?? Is it possible??

Comment: In my opinion it is not possible: Splash and the 2 app icons are not controlled by the user code. Icons are specified in the WMAppManifest.xml - xml does not support #directives. Splash screen is actually any root image with suitable dimensions. If the loader finds such an image, it will use it as splash.

Comment: You can put the shared code in a shared library and have two app projects using that shared lib.

Comment: To change the splash screen at build, you can just add a pre-build event command line that checks the configuration and copies the new splash screen file into the project directory.